# How to catch a disk full error when zipping a file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I use [zip()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zip.html) to compress a file in a Matlab function. How to detect when zip fails because the destination disk is full?

I use Matlab R2014a on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: whats the problem using try/catch? Is no exception thrown or are you unable to isolate the disk full exception?

Comment: Check free space before zipping (for example with http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41904-disk-usage). Should be not less than original file size, otherwise you have a risk.

Comment: I would say call `zip` using a system call instead of using MATLAB's `zip` command.  That way, you can poll and see if there is an error code that is returned.  You check the code and see if it returns a successful flag.